# Oracle sql - select distinct columns based on few columns

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, relational-database

I have a select query like,

```
select a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j from sample_table
```

I need to have distinct set of records from this table, so I put

```
select distinct a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j from sample_table
```

But still, the duplicate columns are coming in the result set, as i,j is differing with a minor change like result, result1, RESULT. I need to get rid of this minor change but want to have it in the result set.

How do I select distinct columns of a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h and also have i,j in the result set.

Comment: If you have multiple `i` and `j` values for a combination of all the other columns, how would you decide which of those multiple values to display? Using an aggregate (min/max) of those values, or based on another column (e.g. most recent if you have a time stamp column you aren't including in the result)?

Comment: Your question is badly written. What column(s) do you want output? What value(s) should it/they have? Give an example. Do not refer to a single value as "i,j" (if that's what you're doing). Use words to make a sentence that describes things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try:

```
select distinct a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, min(upper(i)) i, min(upper(j)) j from sample_table
group by a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;
```

You can consider using min or max combined with substring, upper, lower or whichever suits your requirement.

As alex poole has pointed out, you can also consider having a column with timestamp, so that the latest or the earliest record can be displayed in the result-set.

Comment: The `distinct` is redundant now.

Comment: @AlexPoole: You are right, Please find updated answer.

Comment: They can do that in a join condition also.

Comment: @philipxy: Please edit my answer and add your point as I am unable to figure out how to do what you say!

Comment: @philipxy - you can do what in a join condition? Joining to what? This is a single-table query.

Comment: @philipxy: I meant, i dont understand how we can use a join condition here. So, may be, you can edit my answer and add your point for the benefit of everyone!

Comment: @AlexPoole Sure, I just meant, if there was one, giving sample_table. Join on close_enough(i,j) and select i.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the analytic functions:

```
select a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j
from (select st.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h order by a) as seqnum
      from sample_table
     ) st
where seqnum = 1;
```

This ensures that the values of `i` and `j` come from the same row.

Answer (score 2):

SELECT DISTINCT removes duplicate rows.

If *you* consider certain values to be "the same" either within a column or between two columns, then before rows containing them can be seen as duplicates by the DBMS you have to make them actually the same.

Within a column you can convert each possible variation to one particular variation. This is called converting to a canonical or normal form.

```
select distinct ...,
    case i when "result1" then "result"
        else "RESULT" then "result"
        else "result" then "result"
        else "dOg" then "dog"
        ...
    end as i,
    convert_to_upper_case(j) as j,
    correct_spelling(k) as k
from sample_table
```

If you want to consider values to be the same across columns then you can convert them in that way and compare the canonical forms. Or you can write an expression that compares them and output a single value both columns. This is called an equivalence relation.

```
select distinct ...,g,h,i, i as j
from sample_table
where ...
AND my_canonical_form(g) = my_canonical_form(h)
AND equivalent_according_to_me(i,j)
```

That can be used in generating sample_table if j wasn't really supposed to be different from i there:

```
select distinct ..., t.i, t.i as j -- no u.j
from t,u where ... and close_enough(t.i,u.j)
```

The idea is that canonical_form(x) = canonical_form(y) exactly when equivalent(x,y).

You can either keep both i and j columns or drop one if you want.

Comment: What is `close_enough()`? Why are you making `j` the same as `i`, or assuming they're related at all?

Comment: Read the (poorly written) question.  "the duplicate [sic] columns are coming in the result set, as i,j is differing with a minor change like result, result1, RESULT" He means they are close enough to be all the same value. He refers to a single value expressed differently by i and j as "i,j". Although I can't quite tell if he wants both i and j with one value or just one of them.

Comment: I'm reading that very differently to you then. `i` and `j` as different columns; there are multiple values of each, or at least more than one pair of values for each `a-h`; and the `result*` as just bad examples for one or other column. I am not reading it as "`j` is almost a duplicate of `i`", which I think is what you're saying. `distinct` would 'work' if that was the issue? Have to see if the OP can clarify though.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nishanthi Grashia answer: if you have to show all the values of the different columns, you can use listagg as aggregate function:

```
select same1,same2,same3,same4,same5,same6,same7,same8, 
       listagg(diff1, ',') within group (order by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
     , listagg(diff2, ',') within group (order by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) from (      
            select 1 as same1, 2 as same2 ,3 as same3, 4 as same4,5 as same5,6 as same6,7 as same7, 8 as same8,'m' as diff1,'n' as diff2 from dual
            union
            select 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,'n','o' from dual
            union
            select 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'p','q' from dual
            union
            select 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'p','x' from dual
) qry1 group by same1,same2,same3,same4,same5,same6,same7,same8
```